# Get the id of the last record in the data SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the last ID from at least 4 child-parent relationships between ID's and sum all related ID's quantity. I have tried below -

```
declare @test table (ID int not null, P_ID int null, Qty int not null)
insert into @test(ID, P_ID, Qty) values
(1 , 11  , 1),
(2 , null, 3),
(11, 21  , 2),
(21, 31  , 1),
(31, null, 3),
(12, null, 4)

select
    COALESCE(T2.ID,T1.ID) as ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN T1.P_ID is not null then T1.ID END) as OldID,     
    SUM(Qty) as Qty
from   
    @test T1
        left join
        (select ID from @test 
            GROUP By ID) T2
            on  T2.ID = T1.P_ID

group by
    COALESCE(T2.ID, T1.ID)
```

I am getting output -

```
ID  OldID   Qty
2   NULL    3
11  1       1
12  NULL    4
21  11      1
31  21      2
```

But I want my output will be like this where all ID's with no Parent ID in the first row then all previous ID's will show and `SUM` all relevant ID's quantity -

```
ID  OldID3  OldID2  OldID1  Qty
2                            3  
12                           4
31  21      11      1        7
```

Could someone please help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could something have more than 3 previous ID's? If so, what is the max? 5, 10, 100, ∞?

Comment: @Larnu, at this moment I can see 3 previous ID's, It might be max 5, not more than that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this helps you. I have not tested it thoroughly, so apologies for any bugs.

I'm using a Common Table Expression to get the hierarchy information, then using a dynamic SQL I extract the desired number of previous IDs.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (ID INT NOT NULL, P_ID INT NULL, Qty INT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @test(ID, P_ID, Qty) VALUES
(1 , 11  , 1),
(2 , null, 3),
(11, 21  , 2),
(21, 31  , 1),
(31, null, 3),
(12, null, 4);


IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#hierarchy') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #hierarchy;
CREATE TABLE #hierarchy (
    RootID INT NOT NULL, ID INT NOT NULL, [Qty] INT NOT NULL, SeqIndex INT NOT NULL
);

;WITH hierarchy AS (
    SELECT ID, P_ID, Qty, ID [RootID], 0 [SeqIndex]
    FROM @test
    WHERE P_ID IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT child.ID, child.P_ID, child.Qty, parent.RootID, parent.SeqIndex + 1 [SeqIndex]
    FROM @test child
    JOIN hierarchy parent ON parent.ID=child.P_ID
)
INSERT #hierarchy
SELECT RootID, ID, Qty, SeqIndex 
FROM hierarchy;


DECLARE 
    @DEPTH INT = 3,
    @maxSeqIndex INT = (SELECT MAX(SeqIndex) FROM #hierarchy);

IF (@DEPTH = 0) 
    SELECT RootID, SUM(Qty) [Qty] 
    FROM #hierarchy
    GROUP BY RootID;
ELSE IF (@DEPTH > @maxSeqIndex)
    SELECT NULL
ELSE BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT 
        RootID, 
';
    DECLARE @idx INT = 1;
    WHILE @idx <= @DEPTH BEGIN
        SET @SQL += N'
        (SELECT ID FROM #hierarchy i WHERE i.RootID=o.RootID AND SeqIndex='+CAST(@idx as nvarchar(10))+N') [OldID'+CAST(@maxSeqIndex-@idx+1 as nvarchar(10))+N'],';
        SET @idx += 1;
    END

    SET @SQL += N'
        SUM(Qty) [Qty] 
    FROM #hierarchy o
    GROUP BY RootID;';

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

Of course, the dynamic script could be replaced with a hard-coded SQL if that is OK for you.

Note: performance has not been considered

Comment: Many thanks for your help, could it will be possible not to use Type

Comment: actually.... yes, instead of a table variable a temp table should be used

Comment: I will link this table with couple of other tables, do you think hard coded sql will be good instead of dynamic script

Comment: it depends on your case. if you need only 3 "old" IDs, then go with a hard-coded SQL. i tried to give a generic solution

Comment: did you find my query useful at the end?